# I won't submit form on upload Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, append

Which part of function submit my form on upload image? I won't submit form on upload image. I want on submit button. Which part of code make mi problem? One think this code work okay , but I want submit form on upload photo automation. Also which part of my code maybe not need me for this time?

```
uploadFile(event) {
              const formData = new FormData()
                          formData.append('image', event.target.files[0])
              axios({
                method: "post",
                url: "linkmyapi",
                data: formData,
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                }
              })
                .then(response => {
                  this.items.push(response.data);
                  this.image = "";
                            this.profile_image = ''
                            this.loading = false
                            this.dragAndDropUpload = false
                            this.styleObject.backgroundColor = ''
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  this.loading = false;
            },
            onDropFile(e) {
                        this.dragAndDropUpload = true
                        e.stopPropagation()
                        e.preventDefault()
                        let files = e.dataTransfer.files
                        this.createFile(files[0])
                    },
                    onChangeFile(e) {
                        // this.manualUpload = true
                        let files = e.target.files;
                        this.createFile(files[0])
                    },
                    createFile(file) {
                        if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
                            alert('Select an image')
                            return
                        }
                        let reader = new FileReader()
                        let vm = this
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            vm.profile_image = e.target.result
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
                        this.uploadFile(event)
                    },
                    removeFile() {
                        this.profile_image = ''
                        this.styleObject.backgroundColor = ''
                    },
                    onDragOver () {
                        this.styleObject.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 160, 223, 0.4)'
                    },
                    onDragLeave () {
                        this.styleObject.backgroundColor = ''


    },
```

HTML is

```
  <div class="upload-container">
    <div
        :style="styleObject"
        class="drop drop-profile"
        id="2"
        @dragover.prevent="onDragOver()"
        @dragleave.prevent="onDragLeave()"
        @drop="onDropFile($event)"
        :class="{ 'loading-image': loading }">

        <label v-if="!profile_image" class="label-text label-text-profile">
            Choose or drag
            <br> and drop your
             profile image
             here
             <br>
            <input
                type="file"
                name="profile_image"
                @change="onChangeFile($event)">
        </label>

        <div v-else class="hidden">
            <img :src="profile_image" alt="Profile image" class="image-profile" />

            <div v-if="!loading" class="lc-loupe-trash-container">
                <div @click="removeFile" class="lc-trash"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div v-if="loading" class="spinner-container">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't there some HTML counterpart to your JavaScript?

Comment: Check devtools Network tab, check that your function is called when the form is submitted, provide more code so we can see how you're listening for that event. Just common sense stuff really.

Comment: I can't check it because i have v-validate and can't submit form if all field is not filled

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't so clear, can you try editing it to be a little clearer? Do you want to automatically upload onDrop into drop area or you want to upload onClick of submit button?

Comment: @mistyclech onClick Submit button

Comment: @AleksandarMihailovic the onDropFile event fires the createFile event which then triggers the uploadFile event. you can try taking the uploadFile from the createFile and trigger it onClick of submit